# ZF2 Doctrine2 : How to implement form with relation?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have found a tutorial to implement a form with entities annotations.

[Doctrine entity with zend form](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/doctrine-entity-and-zend-form)

I want to know how to implement with a relation.

This is my code...

My entity :

```
/**
 * Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="account", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_7D3656A4C6798DB", columns={"account_type_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repository\Account")
 * @Annotation\Name("account")
 */
class Account extends EntityAbstract implements InputFilterAwareInterface, UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter
     */
    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"input" = "hidden"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="account_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", nullable=false, unique=true, options={"input" = "text"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text", "class":"test"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Code"})
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", nullable=false, options={"input" = "password"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Mot de passe"})
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password_key", type="string", nullable=false, options={"input" = "password"})
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     */
    protected $passwordKey;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"input" = "checkbox"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"checkbox"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Actif"})
     */
    protected $active = false;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $displayName;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="visible", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"input" = "checkbox"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"checkbox"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Visible"})
     */
    protected $visible = false;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"input" = "date"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"date"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Date de début"})
     */
    protected $startDate = 'now()';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"input" = "date"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"date"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Date de fin"})
     */
    protected $endDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", nullable=false, options={"input" = "password"})
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     */
    protected $token;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="expires", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     */
    protected $expires;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\AccountType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\AccountType", fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="accounts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_type_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Type de compte", "object_manager":"Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" ,"target_class":"Application\Entity\AccountType"})
     */
    protected $accountType;

    ...
```

My controller edit action :

```
    public function editAction()
    {
        try
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
            $repository = $this->getRepository();
            $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id');
            $user = $repository->find($id);

            $builder = new AnnotationBuilder($entityManager);

            $form = $builder->createForm($user);
            $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'Application\Entity\Account'));
            $form->bind($user);

            $view =  new ViewModel();
            $view->setVariable('form', $form);

            return $view;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

I catch this error :

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DoctrineModule\Form\Element\Proxy::setObjectManager() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, string given, called in /Users/thibaud/Sites/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/Proxy.php on line 86 and defined in /Users/thibaud/Sites/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/Proxy.php on line 185

Ok. I know how relations works and how to build a form with doctrine with relations but don't know how to implement the same with anotations. Here is how i build form with a relation :

```
$this->add
(
    array
    (
        'name' => 'accountType',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'options' => array
        (
            'label' => 'Type de compte',
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\AccountType',
            'label_generator' => function($target)
            {
                return $target->getName();
            }
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: You can find this in the doctrine documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/

Comment: Nothing about forms in the doc...

Comment: I know, I pointed you to the docs to learn about relations ...

Comment: Please add your code, else nobody is going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;

 /**
 *
 * @Form\Type("DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect")
 * @Form\Attributes({"required":"required"})
 * @Form\Required(true)
 * @Form\Options({
 *      "label":"Account",
 *      "empty_option": "Please choose",
 *      "target_class": "Application\Entity\Whatever",
 *      "property": "CoolProperty",
 *      "find_method": {
 *          "name": "findBy",
 *          "params": {
 *               "criteria": {"awesomeCriteria": 0},
 *               "orderBy": {"letsSayDate": "ASC"}
 *           }
 *      }
 * })
 */
```

For clarity and shorter codes sake I gave the namespace a alias called Form.

Comment: thank you very much for this post, @cptnk. Do you have any detailed source or tutorial recommendation about using annotated entities to create zend form with doctrine? Thanks again, this was a big help.

Comment: Hi @smozgur It's actually been a while I used zf2 I think I just looked into https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/tree/master/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element and the zendframework Foms Element classes.

Comment: Thank you, @cptnk.